# I defined a new multiply function in Scheme which I think should be wrong, however, it works

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

In scheme, the new multiply function is:

```
( define ( iter b a n)
    ( cond (( = b 0) n)
           (( even? b) ( iter ( / b 2) ( * 2 a) n))
           ( else ( iter ( - b 1) ( / ( * a b) ( - b 1)) ( + a ( * a ( - b 1)))))))

( define ( mul b a)
    ( iter b a 1))
```

the question requires me to use iterative method rather than recursive method to deal with this problem, my thinking is following:

```
for example: ( mul 2 3 ) 

        b     a     n

 begin: 2     3     1
 1    : 1     6     1
 2    : 0     6/0   6
```

Obviously, in step 2, a equals 6/0. That should be impossible. But the function works well. Could anyone explain this? [Here is the example in an online Scheme interpreter.](http://repl.it/KtK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the function doesn't work well. Copy a fresh definition of the procedure, run it again and you'll see the error:

```
(define (iter b a n)
  (cond ((= b 0) n)
        ((even? b)
         (iter (/ b 2) (* 2 a) n))
        (else
         (iter (- b 1) (/ (* a b) (- b 1)) (+ a (* a (- b 1)))))))

(define (mul b a)
  (iter b a 1))

(mul 2 3)
=> /: division by zero
```

In fact, the expected solution would be more along these lines, and notice that special care must be taken in case that `b` is negative:

```
(define (iter a b n)
  (cond ((zero? b) n)
        ((even? b)
         (iter (+ a a) (/ b 2) n))
        (else
         (iter a (- b 1) (+ a n)))))

(define (mul a b)
  (if (< b 0)
      (- (iter a (- b) 0))
      (iter a b 0)))
```

And following your example, here's how the parameters look in each iteration when we execute `(mul 2 3)`:

```
        a     b     n
 begin: 2     3     0
 1    : 2     2     2
 2    : 4     1     2
 3    : 4     0     6
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, and your solution is really comprehensive and elaborate.